# Pandas date_parser, timezone format 'PST' causing error

Tags: python, pandas, date-parsing

I am trying to import a large .csv file with time stamps, and the other columns as floats. The time stamps look as follows:

```
2013-08-01 00:00:00 PST
```

it is in a column labeled 'timestamp' in the df.

I am trying to use pandas to import it, specifically with the read_csv function, and adding my own date parser for the date_parser argument.

I create a date parser as follows:

```
dateparse=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

and execute read_csv as follows

```
df=pd.read_csv(outputFile, sep=',', skiprows=range(1,8), header=None, names=names, usecols=['timestamp', 'power1','power2'], parse_dates=['timestamp'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

However I receive an error,

> time data '# file...... output/R3-12.47-3_swing_node.csv' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'

I believe this is because of the 'PST' at the end of each time stamp. How do I get around this issue? Thank you.

Comment: There is indeed no such timezone: `'PST' in pytz.all_timezones` is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first import the csv, and then convert the date column.

Read in as you have it, and then convert column with dates after imported with:

```
dat['date_column']=pd.to_datetime(dat[original_date_column])
```

Works great for me with the PST on there, no problem.

Comment: Then you can set the timezone of the column after the fact. First, set date/time column to dataframe index with something like `dat=dat.set_index('local_time')`
and then bring into local time with "localize". `dat=dat.tz_localize(timezone, ambiguous='infer')`

Comment: I now get a more general "ValueError: Uknown string format" error

Comment: You can pass it explicitly then: `date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` and then `pd.to_datetime(dat['datetime_column'], format=date_format`

Comment: I get the same error as in my original question when I do that

Comment: You probably have something that isn't a date in the column somewhere, or that is a different format. I'd trouble-shoot it by writing a loop to step through each one by one, and print the string before you try to parse it. That way when the error appears, you'll be able to see which date is messing it up, and figure out how to fix.

Comment: Also, if you add `errors='coerce'` in there, I bet it will work. Then you can see which is a NAN in the output, and where you're getting hung up. If any of this is useful you can press the 'up'  arrow next to the comments... and encourage folks to keep helping you with future Qs, too.

Comment: Hi @TuomasTalvitie, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's good manners/ accepted practice here to either accept an answer, or ask follow-up questions. Also, to up-vote comments that are helpful to you. If you don't do this, people won't be as apt to help you. FYI.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm new here so I am still learning the etiquette. Everyone's advice so far has been great. I will say though I did try the errors='coerce' and I still ended up with string objects in the column, not datetime objects. I will try a loop and see if something  comes up.

Comment: @TuomasTalvitie are you sure you're storing it where you think you are? Try saving it to a different object named whatever (e.g. `test=pd.to_datetime(dat[original_date_column]`); maybe you're just not storing the output correctly?

Comment: I opted to go with just using a csv.DictReader to read in the data. I had to convert the df to a json object anyway, so it was easier just to do from a standard python dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass the parser to the reader, let Pandas figure out the date format on its own:

```
df=pd.read_csv("foo.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[0])
df[0]
#0   2013-08-01
#Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: When I do this, the type for the date object is 'str'

Comment: Did you replace 0 in `parse_dates` with your actual column name or index?